# Unable to insert SQL table values from Powershell into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, powershell

A script gets data from an API, and I'm trying to import that data into SQL Server using a PowerShell.

```
$params = @{
    ServerInstance = "SQLDB1"
    Database="Stage"
}

$InsertResults = @"
INSERT INTO [Stage].[dbo].[ImportTable]([roleID],[roleName])
VALUES ('$roleId','$rolename')
"@

foreach($r in $roles) {
    [int]$roleId = $r.id
    $rolename = $r.name
    Invoke-sqlcm @params -Query $InsertResults }
```

Here, the API spits out ***r*** in roles, which can be r.id (a number value I convert to int) or r.name, a string value, with the goal to put them into a single table side by side, [roleID][roleName]

Well, that's the goal. When checking the table in SQL Server, all I get is

```
|roleID|roleName|
-----------------
|  0   |        |
```

That's if I set roleID to Primary Key. If I don't, it repeats that same row as many times as there are lines of data in the API. If I don't inclued "$rolename = $r.name" then the roleName column just says ".name" and that's that.

What I need looks like

```
|roleID|roleName|
-----------------
|  1   |  role1  |
|  2   |  role2  |
|  3   |  role3  |
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

In your code I see some logic mistake:

You define query string with uninitialized parameters outside query loop. So, your query string never update correctly (expectedly), and you see after executed cmdlet default values for int is 0 and string is NULL (empty string).

So, correct code will be

```
foreach($r in $roles) {
$InsertResults = @"
INSERT INTO [Stage].[dbo].[ImportTable]([roleID],[roleName])
VALUES ('$roleId','$rolename')
"@
    [int]$roleId = $r.id
    $rolename = $r.name
    Invoke-sqlcmd @params -Query $InsertResults }
```

I created array for test

```
$roles = @([pscustomobject]@{id=5; name ="test2"},[pscustomobject]@{id = 6;name ="test"})
```

I tested your code and saw this result

```
|roleID|roleName|
-----------------
|  6   |  test  |
|  6   |  test  |
```

After changed initialization query string (inside loop), i saw

```
|roleID|roleName|
-----------------
|  5   |  test2 |
|  6   |  test  |
```

Your code also can be modified like this:

```
$InsertResults = @"
INSERT INTO [Stage].[dbo].[ImportTable]([roleID],[roleName])
VALUES (`$(roleId),`$(rolename))
"@

foreach($r in $roles) {

$variables = @(
  "roleId=$($r.id)",
  "rolename='$($r.name)'"
)    
    Invoke-sqlcmd @params -Query $InsertResults -Variable $variables}
```